# How to check response is null or not in AMP?

Tags: ajax, amp-html

i need check **event.response.redirect** on form submit-success.

```
<form class="proceed__form" id="proceed__form" method="post"
                      action-xhr="@addtocartlink"
                      target="_top" on="submit-success:AMP.navigateTo(url : event.response.redirect)">

                    <input type="submit" style="font-size:16px;" value="Add To Cart" />

                </form>
```

Comment: You can write your script in `onsubmit` of form tag.

Comment: Not possible in AMP

Comment: are you trying to redirect after a submission?

Comment: But when the event.response.redirect does not return it shows me an error(ORIGINAL NULL) when redirected the response arrives.

Answer (score 0):

That's not yet possible in AMP (there's an open FR for amp-action-macro). A workaround is to set the [`amp-redirect-to` header](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/#redirecting-after-a-submission) your server's response.